# Scala type parameters

Tags: scala, types

I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do the following in scala.

```
  val keys :mutable.HashMap[String,Key[_,_]]= mutable.HashMap.empty

  def concreteKey(id:String)={
    val result = keys.get(id)
    result match{
      case Some(k) => k match{
        case k: Key[String,String] => *some action*
        case k: Key[String,Int] => *some action*
        case k: Key[String,Double] => *some action*
      ...
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to be able to know the specific values of the type parameters when retrieving the element from the list. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

I was thinking about typetags but I cant seem to be able to plug those back into a new instance.

example of what I mean:

```
  def concreteKey(id:String)={
    val result = keys.get(id)
    result match{
      case Some(k) => someObject[k.ValFromTypeTag] // with k.ValFromTypeTag returning the typetag of the keyObject
    }
  }
```

Comment: That won't work due **type erasure**, and if the values are dynamic _(like in this case since they come from a `Map`)_ then `TypeTags` won't work. Can you modify the core that generated the `Map`? Can you describe the meta-problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: A cleaner way would be to not mix different types in the same map (and to not use mutable maps). Also to not use mutable structures.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am trying to make a map of different keys with different types. At runtime one should be able to take one of these keys and create a new object with the same type that the specific key is using. I want to avoid the matching that would be otherwise needed to find the type of the key.

Comment: @Dirax that still sounds very specific, why you want a map of different types? How do you expect to use those values in runtime if you do not even know what are their types? How do you expect to create new instances of each type of you do not know how to instante each of them? - BTW, is the set of types that could be used closed or open?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez The set is closed there are a limited amount possible types. For the problem itself I will try to explain it less specific. I am making a store for objects. However when a client from another language wants to communicate with the store they need to send protobuf messages so it is serlialized. Server side I then make a key for the object with the correct types. Now when a new object with the same key needs to be created it has to have the same type as the key and I want to avoid matching to find it since the key already has the desired type the object should have too.

Comment: Model the set of types as an **ADT** and model the keys as another **ADT** and you can provide a method on the keys that produce a value so you do not have to match, you could override that method using inheritance. Something like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/DC3vcbOaQTaldu0Wc30i3g/2